# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined (Angular Unit-Test)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple test that is structured like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './breadcrumbs.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { BreadcrumbsService } from './breadcrumbs.service';
import { multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory } from 'app/app.component';

fdescribe('BreadcrumbsComponent', () => {
  let component: BreadcrumbsComponent;
  let translateService: TranslateService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BreadcrumbsComponent>;
  let translateServiceStub: Partial<TranslateService>;


let translateServiceStub: Partial<TranslateService>;

translateServiceStub = {
  getBrowserLang: () => {
    return 'de';
  },
  onLangChange: new EventEmitter(),
};

breadcrumbsServiceStub = {
  onUpdateRequest: new Subject(),
  updateBreadcrumbs: () => {
  }
};

  beforeEach((() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BreadcrumbsComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: TranslateService, useValue: translateServiceStub},
        {provide: BreadcrumbsService, useValue: breadcrumbsServiceStub},
      ]
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BreadcrumbsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Currently this error is thrown, which I just can not handle:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

This is my class and the one line in the ngOnInit method causes this error:

```
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit {

  breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[] = [];

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private translate: TranslateService,
              private breadcrumbsService: BreadcrumbsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => this.identifyRoute());
  }
```

...

What am I doing wrong here? Or. Is there a way to get around the error or to mock this line so that the test goes through? I really have no idea how to mock this line in my test.

Comment: Your stub doesn't match the service it's stubbing, `onLangChange` is indeed undefined.

Comment: How can I mock onLangChange. It is a part of a translate service package and defined like this: readonly onLangChange: EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>; I dont have an idea hot to mock this in my test.

Comment: You mock it the same way you're mocking the *other* part of `TranslateService`, `getBrowserLang`; you define a test double as part of your stub of that service. Either an actual observable/event emitter, or just something that has a `subscribe` method with appropriate behaviour.

Comment: I included the event emitter in my stub and subscribed to it. However, this also raises a bug in IDE.

Comment: When you say *"a bug in IDE"*, what do you *mean*? Actually stops your tooling working? Shows you a warning? *What* warning? Is it worse than the thing obviously being undefined?

Comment: Try `useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,`

Comment: My answer works, I used it in production.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I include onLangChange.subscribe(() => {}) in my current translateServiceStub I get this error in my IDE: "Type '{ getBrowserLang(): string; onLangChange: any; (Missing): any; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<TranslateService>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '(Missing)' does not exist in type 'Partial<TranslateService>'"

Comment: @dileepkumarjami I dont know what you mean. I need the multiTranslateHttpLoaderFactory for my translations.

Comment: @Wandrille I will try your approach

Comment: 1. You don't need the translate module in your test bed at all, *you're mocking out the service*. 2. [Edit] to give a [mcve] demonstrating that, then; are you trying to assign the *result* of that expression to the stub object?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do not know exactly what you mean. I have updated the stub in my question. Here the said error is thrown in the IDE.

Comment: That's **not** how you add a property to an object, I'm surprised that's even valid syntactically.

Comment: Look at what TS tries to compile it to: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20TranslateService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getBrowserLang%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20onLangChange%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subscribe%3A%20(callback%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20translateServiceStub%3A%20Partial%3CTranslateService%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AtranslateServiceStub%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getBrowserLang()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'de'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20onLangChange.subscribe(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fixed my mistake, but where do I subscribe to it?

Comment: *Have you?* I'd expect something like `Property 'subscribe' is missing in type '() => void'`. And what do you mean *"where do I subscribe to it"*? Your *component* subscribes to it in `ngOnInit`, that's where this whole thing started.

Comment: My IDE sais: "Type '() => void' is missing the following properties from type 'EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>': __isAsync, emit, subscribe, observers, and 18 more.ts(2740)
translate.service.d.ts(53, 14): The expected type comes from property 'onLangChange' which is declared here on type 'Partial<TranslateService>'"

Comment: Of course it does! `onLangChange` is supposed to be an `EventEmitter`, which `() => {}` is clearly not.

Comment: Finally.. I'm sorry, I was so stressed out that I did not notice the simplest things. It works now, thank you!

Comment: So, how did you fix?

Comment: I have updated the stub in my question. But now I get another error.. -> "Uncaught TypeError: this.translate.getBrowserLang is not a function thrown"

Answer (score -1):

Can you try:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

translateServiceStub = {
    getBrowserLang: () => {
       return 'de';
    },
    onLangChange: of({
       // whatever object is expected
     }),
 };
```